# Does the infinite dimensional rotation group have a "double cover"?

Tags: infinity, infinite-groups

So in 3D, you can rotate stuff however you want, but you'll never get the mirror image, because you need an extra dimension to "flip stuff over". Well in infinite dimensional space, since infinity + 1 = infinity, would the rotational group naturally contain the mirror image "double cover" (if that's what it's called)?

Comment: But adding mirrored orientations still satisfies the group axioms, doesn't it? Clearly nothing breaking closure is possible, inverse is just flipping it back, I don't see how it couldn't be associative, and the identity didn't go away. I may have misused the term double cover though now that I think of it so you may have a point there, but ignoring that I think my question makes ok sense.

Comment: I think what I'm talking about could be defined as the set of isometric linear transformations. If c1 and c2 are columns of the matrix, c1 dot c2 would be 0 I think, and the norm of all columns would be 1, but you could have, for instance, the negative of the unit matrix, and that would be part of the set, yet it wouldn't be rotation, it would be a flip. If you think about it, you can add this flipping to a rotational group without breaking the axioms, but it's a bit counterintuitive to the sort of symmetry that groups usually seem to have.

Comment: How do you define rotation on infinite dimensional space? It's usually defined exactly as isometric transformation that preserves orientation. Anyway, in finite-dimensional case, $GL(n)$ is disconnected (it has two components - matrices with positive and negative determinant), but at least for some Banach spaces (including $l_2$) it's connected.

Comment: @mihaild Thank you for letting me know about that! I guess my question could be answered no if it could be shown that infinite dimensional matrices can have determinants. That's interesting about Banach spaces, gonna look into that.